# C: keyboard and terminal input

Tags: c, input

I only know how to read characters on C with `getchar()`, and
 I'm trying not to go any further than K&R has taught me so far. So
 I'm wondering if there's any way to make my programs more general programs, qsking the user to input a, or several, value(s)  and still
 being able to read with the very useful

```
c = getchar ()) != EOF
```

when I did the 1-20 , 1-21 & 1-22 exercises I realized that I'm always
 giving things values that user can't change, for instance:

```
#define BIG_LINE 16
#define BUFF_SIZE BIG_LINE+2
#define TAB_SIZE 4
```

etc.

> Is there a way that I can be able to use
>
> ```
> $ ./myprogram < file
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> $ cat file | ./myprogram
> ```
>
> and still ask the user to input one or several values with
>   `getchar()`  in both cases?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question seems unclear. Please summarize and highlight the actual question you want to ask.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Do more exercises and you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Both of the example commands you gave (`./myprogram < file` and `cat file | ./myprogram`) specify that the standard input pipe of your program will be used to read the file, so `getchar()` will only retrieve characters from that file and it cannot be used to get interactive input from the user.

Maybe you should be asking a more general question, like "Is it possible to write a C program that reads data from a file and also provides an interactive command-line user interface that involves prompting the user and getting responses?"  If that is what you are trying to do, you could use the C functions `open()` or `fopen()` to open a handle to the input file, while still using the standard input pipe and `getchar()` to get interactive input from the user.

You would need to tell your program the path of the file to open.  The path could be hardcoded in the program, or it could come from an environment variable, or it could be supplied as an argument on the command line (e.g. you could run it with `./myprogram file`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using a UNIX-y system, you can usually do it, not with straight `getchar()` and friends, but with other stdio functions which take a file pointer (such as `fgets()`, `getc()`, and so on) if you create such a pointer to your terminal.

For instance, the following program:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

/*  Returns a file pointer to the terminal, exits on failure  */

FILE * get_terminal(void)
{
    char * tname = ctermid(NULL);

    int fd = open(tname, O_RDWR);
    if ( fd == -1 ) {
        perror("couldn't open terminal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE * fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");
    if ( !fp ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't make file pointer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}

/*  Closes a file pointer to the terminal  */

void close_terminal(FILE * fp)
{
    if ( fclose(fp) == EOF ) {
        perror("couldn't close terminal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/*  Main function  */

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp = get_terminal();

    char buffer[BUFSIZE];

    /*  Get line from stdin and print to stdout  */

    fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    fprintf(stdout, "Line 1: %s", buffer, stdout);

    /*  Get string from terminal and print to terminal  */

    fputs("Enter a string: ", fp);
    fflush(fp);
    fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, fp);
    fprintf(fp, "You entered: %s", buffer);

    /*  Get another line from stdin and print to stdout  */

    fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    fprintf(stdout, "Line 2: %s", buffer, stdout);

    close_terminal(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

gives the following output even if you have your shell redirect both the standard input and the standard output for your program:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ cat input.txt
This is the first line of the file.
This is the second line of the file.

paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./prog < input.txt > output.txt
Enter a string: This is my string.
You entered: This is my string.
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ cat output.txt
Line 1: This is the first line of the file.
Line 2: This is the second line of the file.
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Note that what `ctermid()` produces is not guaranteed to uniquely identify the terminal (and, indeed, on most systems will not - it'll usually be `/dev/tty`) and you're not guaranteed to be able to open it. But it'll probably work on a modern UNIX-y personal computer.

Whether you *ought* to do this is another question entirely. In the vast majority of cases, it would be very unusual and unexpected behavior. If you want the user to be able to specify options such as the size of tab stops, using command line arguments would be a much better solution than getting it interactively, e.g.:

```
./prog --tabstop=4 < input.txt > output.txt
```

K&R covers command line arguments in section 5.10, and the `getopt` library is a common and easy way to work with them.

For more persistent options, using a configuration file or even reading environment variables are other potential solutions.

Obviously all the above is far more advanced than chapter 1 of K&R, but since you said "I'm trying not to go any further than K&R has taught me so far" and then immediately asked how to go further than K&R has taught you so far, this is the kind of thing that's going to happen. The best option of all right now in your case is just to work through the rest of the chapters, and you'll have answered most of your questions by the time you get through to the end.